# Script Errors In VB

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to stop those annoying Runtime Errors in VB. I am using a tabcontrol with a webbrowser item. I am trying to supress the errors. It does not return any errors but at runtime, it doesn't work. This is my code

```
CType(TabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What means 'it doesn't work?' you've verified the property value after assigning it? `msgbox(CType(TabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).ScriptErrorsSuppressed)`, if you still getting script errors on the webbrowser it don't means that the instruction are not working, as you've said there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser control may not be `Item(0)` on the page (it could be in a panel etc), so as an alternative (and safer method) you can use the `Controls.Find` method to search the selected tab and all child controls in order to find the Browser on that tab.

Something like this:

```
'assumes you have a control named WebBrowser1 on the first tab page etc
Dim browserControlName As String = String.Format("WebBrowser{0}", TabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1)
Dim browser As WebBrowser = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Find(browserControlName, True).First, WebBrowser)
browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```